# Prevent "change" event from firing on input when calling .val() from another event

Tags: jquery

I've been staring at this code and googling for a day, and I can't get over the hump. I have an event defined on a textbox

```js
$('#textbox').on('keyup change', function() { /* do stuff */ });
```

When typing into this textbox, I populate a list of buttons in an autocomplete fashion. I have an event bound to the buttons in the autocomplete div. Inside that event, I set the value of `#textbox` to populate from the autocomplete.

```js
$('#textboxOverlay').on('click', 'button', function() {
   // get value from button

   $('#textbox').val(valueFromButton);
}
```

The issue is calling `$('#textbox').val()` fires the `change` event bound to the textbox. That makes sense, but I want to figure out how to **prevent** the `change` event from firing when I'm setting the value of the textbox. Or maybe there's some pattern I'm missing that I should be using instead. I've tried `event.stopPropogation()` and `event.stopImmediatePropogation()` and neither caused a change in behavior.

Comment: Have you tried `event.preventDefault()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prevent a native event from firing.

You can't `.preventDefault` events from another function.

So it you really need to do this, you can use a shared variable to record the condition and only run the "change" callback when the condition is met.

Working example below:

```js
let shouldPreventChange = false;

$('#textbox').on('keyup change', function(e){
  if (e.type === 'change' && shouldPreventChange){
    shouldPreventChange = false;  // Reset condition
    return;
  }
  console.log('Caught event:', e.type);
});

$('#trigger').on('mousedown', function(){
  $('#textbox').val('abcdef');
});

$('#noTrigger').on('mousedown', function(){
  shouldPreventChange = true;
  $('#textbox').val('abcdef');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="textbox"></textarea>
<br>
<button id="trigger">Trigger Change</button>
<button id="noTrigger">No Trigger Change</button>
```

**PS**

You need to use "mousedown" event instead of "click" event because "click" events are only fired after "change" event so the above way won't work.

Comment: Ah, ok. I thought this might be the case. I'll implement tomorrow and see what happens. Appreciate the quick response!